# Discord.js v13: Slash commands are duplicated

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

That seems like some bug or I don't know, but I'm sure this is fixable. All my slash commands are duplicated, first is the newest version of the command, second is some outdated one.

[image: Preview]

I'm assuming it is related to slash command registering, so here it is:

```js
const guild = await client.guilds.cache
            .get("836212492769165363")

        guild.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands).then((cmd) => {
          const getRoles = (commandName) => {
            const permissions = arrayOfSlashCommands.find(x => x.name === commandName).userPermissions;

            if(!permissions) return null;
            return guild.roles.cache.filter(x => x.permissions.has(permissions) && !x.managed)
          }

          const fullPermissions = cmd.reduce((accumulator, x) => {
            const roles = getRoles(x.name);
            if(!roles) return accumulator;

            const permissions = roles.reduce((a, v) => {
              return [
                ...a,
                {
                  id: v.id, 
                  type: 'ROLE',
                  permission: true,
                },
              ]
            }, [])
            return [
              ...accumulator,
              {
                id: x.id,
                permissions,
              }
            ]
          }, [])
          guild.commands.permissions.set({ fullPermissions }).catch((e) => console.log(e))
        })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try restarting your bot using this code:

```js
client.application.commands.set([])
```

Or if you have the guild you can do this:

```js
guild.commands.set([])
```

This *might* take some time to finish but it will work. It will clear all the slash commands so you can put them back without duplicating. From what I see, you have both Guild commands *and* application commands

Comment: i tried to put `client.application.commands.set([])` afore `guild.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands).then((cmd) => {` line and the same with `guild.commands.set([])`, nothing really changed during 5 minutes

Comment: It seems you are setting both global and guild commands. Do you ever do `Guild.commands.set()`?

Comment: in my handler there is only one `guild.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands)` and no `client.application.commands.set()`

Comment: i need to find a method to delete all commands and then create new ones, I tried: `client.application.commands.fetch().then((cmds) => cmds.delete()) - but that didn't work.

Comment: After a goddamn hour it changed! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Global and guild commands are not the same.

## Explanation

---

Global and guild commands are 2 different kinds of slash commands stored in different places.
They both have the limit of 100 and have their own ratelimits.

#### So what's the difference?

---

- Global commands are visible to all guilds and users (including DMs).
- Guild commands on the other hand, is server-specific.

### Demonstration

---

Imagine you have 2 servers, one called `A` and one called `B`.
Now, you registered 2 guild commands inside **A**. Those 2 commands would not appear on **B**.
But if you register another 2 global commands, this would appear on both servers and including DMs.

#### What happened to my code then?

---

You registered both global and guild commands and they both have the same configuration.
That's the reason they all appeared duplicated.

### A fix?

---

There's a way to reset all your guild and global commands.
By using the following code below, it will reset guild commands immediately.
However, you'll have to wait ~1 hour for global commands to update.

```js
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("<guild id>");

    // This takes ~1 hour to update
    client.application.commands.set([]);
    // This updates immediately
    guild.commands.set([]);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this detailed answer, but how do I fix it? Do I have to re-invite the bot, delete integrations, or what? You should add a Solution title in your answer and it will be very appreciated (and marked as answer).

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix:
Kick your bot then re-invite it, worked for me :D

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32638878)